# Most efficient way to determine average # ordered per item per day in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am new to Python and have a large dataset (over 55,000 rows to be exact) in a dataframe with columns UPC, quantity_picked, and date. I am trying to determine the most efficient way to calculate the average quantity picked per UPC per day. Is there a way that this can be done more efficiently than using nested loops?

I have tried the .mean approach but of course it only provides the average quantity picked per UPC per order.
I have also tried implementing .groupby().

```
practice_df_by_UPC = practice_df.groupby('UPC')
print(practice_df_by_UPC)
```

I receive no error but no output either.

I am wanting an output that will allow me to see the average number of items picked by UPC per day. Is there a way to do this for dataframes that I'm not finding that is more efficient, or is a set of nested loops the way to go?

Comment: You can create a list of days you want to check for, loop through it and group by date, then call .mean() on the remaining values . Is this what you're wanting?

Comment: `practice_df.groupby(['date','UPC']).mean()`?

Comment: Groupby without an aggregation function returns a pandas groupby object. Similar to a list generator expression, it doesn't actually do anything with the object until you give it something to do. You can check this by using `print` or `type` on your `practice_df_by_UPC`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions, and thanks @G.Anderson for the explanation. I shall these.

Comment: When trying what was suggested by @QuangHoang I get the following error: "ValueError: No axis named UPC for object type <class 'type'>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching out groupby with set_index and doing some extra troubleshooting, the following code resolved the issue and accomplished the goal of determining the average quantity for a specified UPC and date (example UPC and date plugged in):

```
#creating multi-index based on date and UPC
practice_df.set_index(['date_expected', 'UPC'], inplace=True)

print('Mean:')
print(practice_df.loc['2019-05-15', '0000000004011'].mean())
```

The inplace=True addition got rid of the remaining error. While printing the dataframe it is now multi indexed organized first by date, then by UPC.

Comment: Also, for other beginners who get confused with set_index and groupby: see the resource below, this is what helped me get the rest of the way through - [pandas multi-index and groupby datacamp article](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-multi-index)